# Block access to all files except certain file types with .htaccess

Tags: file, .htaccess, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a .htaccess file to prevent a visitor from directly accessing files in a specific folder with the exception of files with certain extensions.

Currently I'm blocking everything using

```
Deny from all
```

For example, lets assume I have a folder with the following files inside:

```
report.pdf
data.doc
cabbage.gif
pens.png
movies.docx
```

How would I go about blocking access to ALL files **except** those with the extentions .gif and .png?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gif$ allow_extension=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.png$ allow_extension=1

Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow From env=allow_extension
```